# Is it better to use use the standard deviation (SD) or standard error (SE) when plotting error bars?

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation, standard-error

There's a great deal of variability in whether people use the SD or SE when plotting error bars. Why would someone choose one over the other?

Comment: SE is not often plotted: CI (which is its extension) is more informative. SD is used for giving impression of data variation, not of the mean certainty.

Comment: My mistake - the 95% CI, which is derived in part from the SEM, is plotted. +1 for basically summarized my answer in one sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Answer re-posted from [here](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/201/):

> **Is it better to plot graphs with SD or SEM error bars? (Answer: Neither)**
>
> There are better alternatives to graphing the mean with SD or SEM.
>
> **If you want to show the variation in your data:**
>
> If each value represents a different individual, you probably want to
> show the variation among values. Even if each value represents a
> different lab experiment, it often makes sense to show the variation.
>
> With fewer than 100 or so values, create a scatter plot that shows
> every value. What better way to show the variation among values than
> to show every value? If your data set has more than 100 or so values,
> a scatter plot becomes messy. Alternatives are to show a
> box-and-whiskers plot, a frequency distribution (histogram), or a
> cumulative frequency distribution. What about plotting mean and SD?
> The SD does quantify variability, so this is indeed one way to graph
> variability. But a SD is only one value, so is a pretty limited way to
> show variation. A graph showing mean and SD error bar is less
> informative than any of the other alternatives, but takes no less
> space and is no easier to interpret. I see no advantage to plotting a
> mean and SD rather than a column scatter graph, box-and-wiskers plot,
> or a frequency distribution. Of course, if you do decide to show SD
> error bars, be sure to say so in the figure legend so no one will
> think it is a SEM.
>
> **If you want to show how precisely you have determined the mean:**
>
> If your goal is to compare means with a t test or
> ANOVA, or to show how closely our data come to the predictions of a
> model,  you may be more interested in showing how precisely the data
> define the mean than in showing the variability. In this case, the
> best approach is to plot the 95% confidence interval of the mean (or
> perhaps a 90% or 99% confidence interval). What about the standard
> error of the mean (SEM)? Graphing the mean with an SEM error bars is a
> commonly used method to show how well you know the mean,  The only
> advantage of SEM error bars are that they are shorter, but SEM error
> bars are harder to interpret than a  confidence interval. Whatever
> error bars you choose to show, be sure to state your choice. Noticing
> whether or not the error bars overlap tells you less than you might
> guess.
>
> **If you want to create persuasive propaganda:**
>
> If your goal is to emphasize small and unimportant differences in your data, show your error bars as SEM,  and hope that your readers think they are SD If
> our goal is to cover-up large differences, show the error bars as the
> standard deviations for the groups, and hope that your readers think
> they are a standard errors. This approach was advocated by Steve Simon
> in his excellent weblog. Of course he meant it as a joke. If you don't
> understand the joke, review  the differences between SD and SEM.